# How can I replce last space in a Java string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I try doing something like these:

```
String result = "Most Trees Are Blue ";

//Should be return a string without last space

return result.replaseAll("REGEX", "");
```

result must be "Most Trees Are Blue", i can do:

```
return new StringBuilder(result).deleteCharAt(result.length()-1).toString();
```

but I want do it with regex.

- How can I do it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i think it would remove also the leading spaces.

Comment: @AvinashRaj While true, OP's example doesn't include leading spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a regular expression, you could use `replaceAll("\\s+$", "")` like

```
String result = "Most Trees Are Blue ";
result = result.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
System.out.printf("'%s'%n", result);
```

This `\\s+` will match one (or more) white space characters, the `$` indicates at the end of `String` and then the `""` is the replacement value. Output is,

```
'Most Trees Are Blue'
```

You might also use [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) like

```
String result = "Most Trees Are Blue ".trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach using regular expression as you stated would be ...

```
String result = "Most Trees Are Blue ".replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
System.out.println(result); //=> "Most Trees Are Blue"
```